# Flutter Dismiss Alert Dialog Navigation Issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

> I am currently trying to navigate back to the existing screen from an opened alert dialog box. When I try to do so using this code:

```
onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
```

> I am diverted back to the opened alert dialog box but I would like it to be closed and not open on return to the original screen. Is there a way of doing this besides using

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(
   MaterialPageRoute(
   builder: (context) =>
   CreatePost()));
```

[image: Opened Dialog box]

> This is what I currently am diverted back to: an opened dialog box.
>
> Here is the alert dialog code:

```
AlertDialog(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
      Radius.circular(10.0),
    ),
   ),
   content: Stack(
     overflow: Overflow.visible,
     children: <Widget>[
       Positioned(
         right: -40.0,
         top: -40.0,
         child: InkResponse(
           onTap: () {
             Navigator.of(context).pop();
           },
           child: CircleAvatar(
             child: Icon(
               Icons.close,
               color: Colors.white,
             ),
             backgroundColor: Colors.red,
             maxRadius: 20.0,
           ),
         ),
       ),
```

> I can use this code to navigate back to the appropriate screen but it doesn't work well with multiple screens using the same logic:

```
Navigator.of(context) .push(MaterialPageRoute( builder: (context) => CampaignPage1())) .then((result) { Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Comment: Please post the full code so proper help and guide can be given.

Comment: Do you want to Navigate to the screen behind the Alert Dialog or another screen?

Comment: @SimranAswani Yes, to the screen behind the alert dialog.

Comment: The place where you are calling your Alert Dialog must have a 'context' of itself

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling your Alert Dialog like this:

```
class FancyAlertDialog {
  static showFancyAlertDialog(
    BuildContext context,
    String title,
    String message, {
    bool dismissable = false,
    Icon icon,
     String labelPositiveButton,
    String labelNegativeButton,
  VoidCallback onTapPositiveButton,
    VoidCallback onTapNegativeButton,
  }) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: dismissable,
      child: Dialog(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(12.0),
          ),
        ),
        child: Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(12.0),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: icon ?? Container(height: 0),
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 16.0,
                top: 2.0,
                right: 16.0,
                bottom: 8.0,
              ),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: Text(title,
                        style: khomeStyle.copyWith(
                            color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16)),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  Text(message,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: khomeStyle.copyWith(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 13,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                  SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(16.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          child: Text(
                            labelNegativeButton.toUpperCase(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: onTapNegativeButton,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                      Center(
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(16.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          color: kOrange,
                          child: Text(
                            labelPositiveButton.toUpperCase(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: onTapPositiveButton,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When you want to call this Alert Dialog you can call it like this:

```
FancyAlertDialog.showshowFancyAlertDialog(*Supply your arguments here*)
```

When you call this you can call the `Navigator.pop(context)` function on the call of the alert dialog as a parameter

```
FancyAlertDialog.showshowFancyAlertDialog(
...
 onTapPositiveButton: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
                print('tap positive button');
              },
)
```

The text and function for the two buttons can be specified on call.